# install symbolic links with coreutils install

Tags: shared-libraries, gnu-coreutils

I built a library and I want to install the library to `/usr/local/lib` using coreutils `install`. The result of the build looks as follows:

```
libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1
libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.1
libfoo.so.1.1
```

I want to retain the symbolic links and `install` the files as is to `/usr/local/lib`. However, if I run

```
install libfoo* /usr/local/lib
```

the symbolic links are resolved and `/usr/local/lib` looks as follows:

```
libfoo.so
libfoo.so.1
libfoo.so.1.1
```

In other words, these are all real files and no symbolic links.

The manpage of `install` does not contain any information about resolving symbolic links. How can I `install` symbolic links?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wondered about this too. After [looking at the source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) it would appear that `install` is pretty aggressive about resolving links at install time. Here are some of the defaults it passes to `cp`; the relevant ones don't get overridden later.

```
cp_option_init (struct cp_options *x)
{
  cp_options_default (x);
  x->copy_as_regular = true;
  x->reflink_mode = REFLINK_NEVER;
  x->dereference = DEREF_ALWAYS;
  x->hard_link = false;
  x->preserve_links = false;
  x->preserve_mode = false;
  x->symbolic_link = false;
(...)
```

The workaround would be to use `cp` + `chmod`.

Answer (score 3):

Please be note that the `install` utility always dereferences symlinks.

Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713502/why-install-bin-and-install-data-always-remove-softlink-when-installation).

To copy files while preserving everything (symlinks, hard links, mode, etc) you can use `cp -a`

You can also use tar:

`tar c -C source_dir file1 ... fileN | tar xv -C dest_dir`

Be aware that both `cp -a` and `tar` will preserve user and group and that those files must probably be owned by root:root at the destination. You may have to add a chown afterwards.