# Why $(INSTALL_BIN) and $(INSTALL_DATA) always remove softlink when installing files in Makefile

Tags: makefile, openwrt

In OpenWrt package Makefile, at install section, the following code will remove the softlink from a lib* file and copy instance to $(1)

In Build/Compile Section, we built out 3 libs under ${PKG_BUILD_DIR}

```
${PKG_BUILD_DIR}/libapi.so          //  ->  libapi.so.1.0
${PKG_BUILD_DIR}/libapi.so.1.0      //  ->  libapi.so.1.0.1
${PKG_BUILD_DIR}/libapi.so.1.0.1
```

**In Build/Installdev and Package/api/install Section, if $(INSTALL_BIN)/$(INSTALL_DATA) is used to copy these 3 libs from ${PKG_BUILD_DIR} to $(1)/usr/lib/, the softlik will be removed.**

```
define Package/api/install
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libapi.so  $(1)/usr/lib/
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libapi.so.1.0  $(1)/usr/lib/
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libapi.so.1.0.1  $(1)/usr/lib/
endef
```

**The only way I have to use is $(CP) or "cp -f"**

But I'm not sure that $(CP) will keep the -m0755 flags to these libs since I need the libs to be excutable on the target board.

```
define Package/api/install
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libapi.so*  $(1)/usr/lib/
endef
```

**How can I let $(INSTALL_BIN) keep softlink ?**

Logs and variables:

```
INSTALL_BIN  = install -m0755
INSTALL_DATA = install -m0644
CP           = cp -fpR
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the `install` utility always dereferences symlinks (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35560730/7233423)).

To copy files while preserving everything (symlinks, hard links, mode, etc) you can use `cp -a`.

You can also use `tar`:

```
tar c -C source_dir file1 ... fileN | tar xv -C dest_dir
```

Be aware that both `cp -a` and `tar` will preserve user and group and that those files must probably be owned by root:root at the destination. You may have to add a `chown` afterwards.

Comment: what if "cp -afpR" ? 
I noticed that "-p" option means "same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps" 
with cp -p , does it mean that here is no need to add chown afterwards ?

Comment: `-a` is already a combination of flags (`man cp` or `cp --help`) in order to preserve everything. If you want to preserve less, then remove `-a` and add your own flags, like `cp -d`

Comment: so with"-a", does it mean there is no need to add chown after cp?

Comment: You should try it and see what happens, and if it doesn't do what you want you can adjust the options and/or add chown.  It's much more efficient to just try it than to ask on SO and wait for someone to find the time to answer.  xhienne is simply pointing out that you should check the ownership after the copy operation to be sure it's what you want.